# Why doesn't ruby have a block_return (return from block)

Tags: ruby, return, break

I can think of a number of cases where block_return or return_block would be useful, but particularly in the case of yield.  For example, the common problem of something like:

```
def with_file(name)
  f = file.open(name, 'r')
  yield f
  close f
end
```

Which can be broken thusly:

```
def some_scope
  with_file("test") { |f|
    line = f.readline.chomp
    puts line
    return if line == "done" 
  }
end
```

Because the return will return from the some_scope method, as opposed to going back to the yield.  I know that this situation can be fixed by using 'ensure' after the yield, but there are certainly cases where we want to be able to return a value from the yield, and we have no way to short circuit that with a simple 'block_return', and possibly end up having to wrap all of our block in an 'if/then' instead.

It seems like it could be useful to have a way to return at the block scope, to be able to stop executing the block, and possibly to return a value for that block.  Is there a reason this isn't in the Ruby language - is it going to cause some ambiguities or breaks that I haven't thought of?

Comment: If you're ever wondering "Why?" the answer is almost always "Because [Matz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yukihiro_Matsumoto)!" Someone had to make a call here, and that's who it usually falls to.

Comment: I'm not sure your `some_scope` makes sense as a bona fide example. Currently if will "return" `nil` regardless because if the first line of the file is "done" then `return if line == "done"` results in `return nil`, if the first line of the file is not "done" then `return if line == "done"` evaluates as `nil`.

Comment: Ruby has plenty of other control flow expressions for returning early from a block such as `break`, `next`, `throw/catch`. All of them let you pass a return value.

Comment: @max next(val) does what I want!  Thanks!

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, I'm aware it's returning nil, I was mixing examples which was probably not the best way to answer the question.  But I have the answer with 'next(val)'

Comment: @DavidLjungMadisonStellar feel free to answer the question yourself.